# Manipulating stdin and redirect to stdout in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a simple python script where

1. it takes values from stdin
2. replaces a specific matched word
3. passes on the output with the NEW value back to stdout

I only have the part where it takes the values from stdin and looks for the matching words, I'm a bit stuck after that.

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    matchObj = re.search(r'<something>(.*)</something>',line)
    if matchObj:
        oldWord = matchObj.group(1)
        print oldWord
```

Contents of foo

```
<something>REPLACEME</something>
<blah>UNTOUCH</blah>
```

Ideally if I run this command

```
cat foo | ./test.py
```

I would get something like this

```
<something>NEWWORD</something
<blah>UNTOUCH</blah>
```

Comment: RTFM [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.sub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)?

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(<something>)REPLACEME(</something>)',
                            r'\1NEWWORD\2',
                            line))
```

Running the above on your example data:

```
$ echo '<something>REPLACEME</something>\n<something>UNTOUCH</something>' | python2 test.py
<something>NEWWORD</something>
<blah>UNTOUCH</blah>
```

Note that parsing XML with regular expressions is probably a bad idea. The Python standard library comes with a [number of XML modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html).

Here's an example:

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(sys.stdin)
root = tree.getroot()

for node in root.iter('something'):
    if node.text == 'REPLACEME':
        node.text == 'NEWWORD'

tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

The above would work just the same:

```
$ echo '<root><something>REPLACEME</something>\n<blah>UNTOUCH</blah></root>' | python2 test.py
<root><something>REPLACEME</something>
<blah>UNTOUCH</blah></root>
```

Answer (score 1):

firs if you run `cat foo | ./test.py` you got `test.py: command not found` , you need to run this : `cat foo |python ./test.py` .

then the output of your code will be :

```
REPLACEME
```

but for the output that you want,  you need to use `re.sub()`:

```
import re
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    matchObj = re.sub(r'<something>(.*)</something>','<something>NEWWORD</something>',line)
    if matchObj:
        print matchObj
```

output :

```
<something>NEWWORD</something>

<blah>UNTOUCH</blah>
```

Also as a pythonic way you can use The [`ElementTree XML API`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)